# Create Translucent status bar and toolbar in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, toolbar, statusbar

I would like to create a trunslucent status bar and toolbar , i tried few things but could not make it work , basically i want to do the thing as shown in the below attached image and thank you in advance for any help .

- This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="@null"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#FF5722"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false" />


</LinearLayout>
```

- This is my style xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Tab" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

- This is the example i want ( surrounded by red line )

[image]